# NSButton with Mouse Down/Up and Key Down/Up

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I need a NSButton that gives me 2 events, one when the button is pressed down (NSOnState) and one when the button is released (NSOffState) and so far i've got it working with the mouse (intercepting the mouseDown: event). But using a keyboard shortcut doesn't work, it fires a NSOnState once and then after a delay really often. Is there any way to get a button that fires NSOnState when pressed and NSOffState when released?

My current subclass of NSButton looks like this and unfortunately works using a delegate:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setTarget:self];
    [self setAction:@selector(buttonAction:)];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [_delegate button:self isPressed:YES];
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}

-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [_delegate button:self isPressed:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button can be set to send mouse events at both times by using `-sendActionOn:`:

```c
[self.button sendActionOn: NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask];
```

Handling keyboard events similarly seems more difficult. If you don't need the event exactly at the same time the highlight is removed from the button, you could override NSButton's `-performKeyEquivalent:` so that it will e.g. send the action twice.

```c
- (BOOL) performKeyEquivalent: (NSEvent *) anEvent
{
    if ([super performKeyEquivalent: anEvent])
    {
        [self sendAction: self.action to: self.target];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

If you do need the event at the same time, I think you need to use a custom button cell (by creating a subclass of NSButtonCell and setting the button's cell in the initializer) and override its `-highlight:withFrame:inView:`:

```c
- (void)highlight:(BOOL)flag
        withFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame
           inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [super highlight: flag withFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];

    if (flag)
    {
        // Action hasn't been sent yet.
    }
    else
    {
        // Action has been sent.
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do with this button? Are you sure the button is where all of it lives? Maybe not a method instead?

Comment: [self.button sendActionOn: NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask]; I can't get it written in swift (I now have self.sendAction(on: .leftMouseDown)). I tried .leftMouseUp.union(etc..) but got an error (self.sendAction(on: .leftMouseDown | .leftMouseUp) leads to: Protocol 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'NSEvent.EventTypeMask' conform to 'BinaryInteger'). What would be the swift version of it? If I get right, does this mean that the button action would be fired twice: on on mouseDown and one on mouseUp? Thanks

Comment: if it can help (not as straightforward as in objC):                                                                                          let maskUp = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseUp.rawValue
let maskDown = NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown.rawValue
let mask = Int( maskUp | maskDown ) // cast from UInt
self.sendAction(on: NSEvent.EventTypeMask(rawValue: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.RawValue(mask)))